# "Back" button not displaying in navigationItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I came across a very subtle issue.

Usually things are okay, but occasionally the current UIviewController has no title. When I call another viewcontroller called via

```
[[fruitDB navigationController] pushViewController:fruitc animated:YES];
```

there is no "back" button. The area on the top left of the navigation bar is still active though and I can go back.

How can I make sure the back button is still active, even if there is no title?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the backBarButtonItem of the navigation item of the view controller.

Specifically, somewhere in viewController1 before pushing viewController2, do the following...

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

When you push viewController2, the back button shown will be the backBarButtonItem of viewController1.

Note: Technically, apple recommends overriding the navigationItem method in your view controller, and adding buttons there, but it's really not an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you push the next view controller why don't you try:
`self.title = @"Back";`??

Comment: then add in "viewWillAppear" `self.title=@"";`

Comment: The problem of this method is that you can see changed title during transition...